# what is the alternative for ROWNUM in MySQL in query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello when I'm executed the below query in oracle it works fine but in MySQL it is showing error for ROWNUM.

```
SELECT ROWNUM , key_value , new_rec 
FROM table1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT key_value 
                   FROM table2 
                   WHERE table1.key_value = table2.key_value 
                 );
```

what is the alternative for for this in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

As a starter: without an `ORDER BY`, it is undefined which row will get which `ROWNUM`.

Now, assuming that you do have a sorting column (say `id`), it depends on the version of MySQL that you are running.

In MySQL 8.0, just use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT row_number() over(order by id) rn, key_value, new_rec 
FROM table1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT key_value FROM table2 WHERE table1.key_value = table2.key_value );
```

In earlier versions, you would use user variables.

```
SET @rn := 0;
SELECT @rn := @rn + 1 rn, t.*
FROM (
    SELECT key_value , new_rec 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT key_value FROM table2 WHERE table1.key_value = table2.key_value )
    ORDER BY id
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

`ROWNUM` represent sequence value so, You can use `row_number()` to create unique sequence :

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ?) AS ROWNUM , key_value , new_rec 
FROM table1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT key_value 
                   FROM table2 
                   WHERE table1.key_value = table2.key_value 
                 );
```

Note :  Use identity column insstead of `?`.